# Send and recieve files in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-sockets

So,  I am making something in my computer science class where you can send files to a remote server and that works, but cant recv them back.
SERVER.PY

```
import socket   # Import socket module
import os #imports os module
def RecvFile():
    while True: # allows it to always save files and not have to be restarted.
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Connection Accepted From',addr)# this prints out connection and port
        print ("File is comming ....")
        file = c.recv(1024)     #recieves file name from client


        f = open(file,'wb')      #open that file or create one
        l = c.recv(1024)         #now recieves the contents of the file
        while (l):

            print ("Receiving...File Data")
            f.write(l)            #save input to file
            l = c.recv(1024)      #get again until done
        print("The file",file,"has been succesfully saved to the server\nConnection from:",addr)
        f.close()

def SendFile():
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection Accepted From",addr)
    filename = c.recv(1024)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        s.send("EXISTS"+str(os.pthat.getsize(filename)))
        response = c.recv(1024)
        if response[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                s.sendall(f.read)
            f.close()
    else:
        s.send("ERR")
    s.close()

def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('139.59.173.187', 8000)) # Binds port and IP address
    s.listen(3)

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        option = c.recv(1024)
        if option == "S":
            RecvFile()
        elif option == "R":
            SendFile()
        else:
            s.send("Incorrect input".encode('utf-8'))


main()

#if errors occur
c.close()
```

I think the server.py is the problem

Client .py

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('139.59.173.187',8000))
    print("=========================Welcome to the File System =========================")
    option = input("Here are your options:\n--> Press S to upload files\n--> Press R to retrieve files")
    if option == "S" or option == "s":
        s.send("S".encode('utf-8'))
        file_name = input("Please input the file name\n>>>")
        name = input("What would you like it to be saved as?\n>>>")

        s.send(name.encode('utf-8'))

        with open(file_name,'rb') as f:
            s.sendall(f.read())
        print("File has been sent to the server")
        main()

    elif option == "R" or option == "r":
        s.send("R".encode('utf-8'))
        filename = input("What is the filename you wish to recieve\n>>>")
        s.send(filename.encode('utf-8'))

        print ("File is comming ....")
        f = open(filename,'wb')      #open that file or create one
        l = c.recv(1024)         #now recieves the contents of the file
        while (l):

            print ("Receiving...File Data")
            f.write(l)            #save input to file
            l = c.recv(1024)      #get again until done
        print("The file",filename,"has been succesfully saved to your computer")
        f.close()
```

I have put 7 hours into learning this and the asignment is due in friday. rather than saying the code could you comment how it works etc.

Comment: Are you getting an specific error?

Comment: The error is a broken pipe however i think i mah have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

In server.py, `SendFile` and `RecvFile` both use a socket object `s` that they have no access to. I recommend that you pass it as an argument :

```
def RecvFile(s):
#...

def SendFile(s):
#...
```

And then in main :

```
if option == "S":
    RecvFile(s)
elif option == "R":
    SendFile(s)
```